# Format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'float *' How to fix?

Tags: c

What's my mistake?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 int main()
{
    int j, i, F, n=4;
    float**matr; float**mass;
    printf("Начальная матрица:\n*");
    mass = (float**)malloc(n*sizeof(float));
    matr = (float**)malloc(n*sizeof(float*));
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        matr[i]=(float*)malloc(n*sizeof(float));
        for(j=0; j<n; j++) matr[i][j]= 9+rand()%20;
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<n; j++) printf("\t%2.2f",matr[i]);
        printf("\n");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) free (matr[i]);
    free(matr);
    free(mass);
    }
}
```

Problem is here:

```
for(j=0; j<n; j++) printf("\t%2.2f",matr[i]);
```

Comment: Closing as a typo -- do `matr[i][j]`

Comment: The argument passed to `printf`'s `%f` specifier is `matr[i]` which is a pointer, not a `double` (or promoted `float`). The warning tells you that.

Comment: Welcome, please don't post images, post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem. May I suggest you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @WeatherVane I got it thanks o lot

Comment: @JohnFilleau it helped :) u’re an angel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `printf("\t%2.2f",matr[i][j]);` to print the value what you are assigned.